# Angular: Run form group async validator only if all the controls are not null

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

How do I invoke `FormGroup` validation only after the user fills out all the controls in that group. Currently it's invoked on filling each control.

Answer (score 2):

Angular 5 `FormGroup` class has a new property called [onUpdate](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#members). From the documentation:

> updateOn: Serves as the default updateOn value for all child NgModels below it (unless a child has explicitly set its own value for this in ngModelOptions). Potential values: 'change' | 'blur' | 'submit'

```
<form [ngFormOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}">
   <input name="one" ngModel>  <!-- this ngModel will update on blur -->
</form>
```

If you set it to `submit` the form will be validated on form submit only. `ngModelOptions` parameter allows you to control each form control independently.

```
<input type="name" ngModel [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'submit'}">
```

These new properties can be used in reactive forms as well:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(null, {
         validators: Validators.required,
         updateOn: 'blur'
    }),
 }, { updateOn: 'submit' });
```

Comment: My requirement was to not enforce `required` on all form controls, but to trigger validation only if all controls in that group are non empty. Anyways, I'm now doing this `if (Object.keys(control.value).some(key => !control.value[key]))
      return of(null);` in the `FormGroup` validator.